# Pedlar vs. peddler

Tags: etymology, orthography, suffixes, agent-noun-suffix

The [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=peddler) entry for *peddler* reads:

> **late 14c.** (c.**1300** as a surname, Will. Le Pedelare), from peoddere, peddere (c.1200, mid-12c. as a surname), of unknown origin. It has the appearance of an agent noun, but no corresponding verb is attested in Middle English. Perhaps a dim. of ped "panier, basket," also of unknown origin, but this is attested only from late 14c. **Pedlar**, preferred spelling in U.K., is attested from **late 14c**.

Going by the above, it's difficult to understand which came first—*pedlar* or *peddler*. The former is the recommended BrE spelling and the latter the AmE equivalent. If *pedlar* was the original spelling, why the switch to *peddler* (with an extra *d* as well as a change in suffix) in AmE? The word *peddle* is itself a [back-formation](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=peddle) from *peddler* dated ~1837 which makes it doubtful as the source.

Other similarly suffixed words such as *liar*, *beggar*, and *bursar* appear to have made the transition untarnished.

Comment: Perhaps the date 1837 provides some kind of clue. That was not long after the spelling reform movement took hold in the U.S., and maybe the back-formation was accepted for whatever reason.

Comment: In light of @StoneyB's answer, I'm interested to hear what the OED has to say about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The verb *peddle* and the noun *peddler* are older than your source suggests. [Middle English Dictionary](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=139341090&egdisplay=compact&egs=139343224) gives both *pedelare* and *pedelere* in the 14th Century. As spelling began to be regularized we find:

Mr. A. Boyer, *The Royal Dictionary*, 1728 (a French & English dictionary):

> Pedlar *or* Pedler, S. *Un ramonneur* ou *colporteur, petit mercier* ou *clincailler*, que porte sa boutique sur soi.
>   To peddle, V. N. *Faire le metier de colporteur, de petit mercier,* ou *de clincaillier*

*A Dialogue Between Timothy and Philatheus*, 1710:

> a *License to Hawk and Peddle with*

Christopher Wase, *Dictionarium Minus*, 1675 (a Latin & English dictionary):

> Agino, are. *To peddle; to haggle.*

*The History of the Life and Acts of ... Edmund Grindal*, 1710, records the Archbishop’s *Injunctions* under “*Anno* 1571”:

> No Peddler, or other, to set his Wares to sell in Church Porch or Churchyard

If *peddle* is indeed a back-formation from *pedlar*, it fell together with a homonym spelt both *peddle* and *piddle*

D. Fenning, *The Royal English Dictionary*, 1743:

> To PE’DDLE, V. N. [commonly written *piddle] to be busy about trifles.
>   To PI’DDLE, V. N. [derived by Skinner from *pecciolo*, Ital. or *petit*, Fr. Little; and Johnson supposes it comes from *peddle*, which Skinner says, signifies to deal in small things] to pick at table; to eat squeamishly; to trifle, and attend to small parts rather than the main.

This, too, has a fairly long history:

Guy Miege, *The Short French Dictionary*, 1701:

> to Piddle, *pinocher, manger en degouté.*

Thomas Durfey, *The Marriage-Hater Match’d*, 1692.

> a good fat Haunch of Venison, boyl’d with Colliflowers, would do well to piddle over.

Robert Harris,*Works*,1654:

> A sick man that hath a bad stomach, listens after this thing and that thing (he cannot away with all kind of meats) and when he hath what he wished for, he doth but piddle a little at it

William Hinde, *The Office and Vse of the Morall Law of God*, 1623:

> and yet dare you be so bold, as to piddle and picke out something out of his writings

Small wonder that one who does a *business* in trifles should be conflated with one who *busies* himself with trifles.

Comment: Excellent, +1; but could we use "peddler" in figurative sense, e.g., _peddler in pipe dreams_? Or, strictly speaking, is "peddler"  reserved only for those who deal in illegal drugs?

Comment: @Carlo_R Google claims 48,000 hits on "peddler of dreams". Of course Google lies a lot.

Comment: How does _pedlar_ figure in all this? Did _pedlar_ and _peddler_ coexist in the UK for at least a couple of centuries? BTW, Etymonline states that _peddle_ is a back-formation of _peddler_ rather than _pedlar_.

Comment: @coleopterist As you see, The Royal Dictionary in 1728 gives them as variant spellings. *Peddler* is shown here 1571 and is still the preferred spelling in John Walker's "Critical Pronouncing Dictionary", first published in 1791 and still being printed 40 years later, not only in England but also in Germany and the US. Walker gives it as "Pedler [yes, with 'er']... properly *Peddler*" So basically a back-formation from one is a back-formation from the other.

Answer (score 3):

Chambers Dictionary, (reliable where Scottish usage is concerned, and fairly good regarding usage in England) says that *pedder* was the original form (or *pether* in Walter Scott), and a pedder was distinguished from a *hawker* by travelling on foot rather than with a cart.  This became *pedlar* in the same way as *tinkler* sprang from *tinker* (??); *peddle* was a later coinage/verbification influenced by *piddle*; and *peddler* is 'largely U.S', presumably used by people who don't know the etymology.

It sounds plausible: but has anybody else found any link between *pedlar* and foot travel?

Comment: MED certainly gives *pedder(e)* at the same time as *pedelare* and *pedelere*, with a single instance a couple hundred years earlier, and suggests an origin in "ML pedārius, one who goes on foot & pedāre, to walk." *Tinkler* is, I believe, Scottish dialect for *tinker*; I remember encountering it in John Buchan's work.

Comment: *OED 1* speculates that intransitive and transitive senses of the verb are distinct words, but the argument does not convince me. Towards the end of the 18th century the spelling *peddler* seems to be particularly popular in Scottish dialect writing. The versions with *l* go at least as far back as the early 14th century, and the verb to the 16th century.